# getting divs to sit next to each other

Tags: html, css-float

I have a couple divs in a fiddle here and what I'm trying to do is get the purple div to sit next to the orange div horizontally and have them scroll horizontally in their container. Right now, they only scroll up and down, but I want it to be side to side.

http://jsfiddle.net/L4hfx/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your slider image divs are too wide to fit next to each other inside the container div.

Here is a simplified working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/L4hfx/19/

---

This means that instead of this:
[image]

You have this:
[image]